# Sticky nav working on localhost but not when I upload online (in webkit browsers)

Tags: jquery, webkit, nav, sticky

I have created a sticky nav which stays fixed to the top of the page when the user scrolls. It should then return to its normal position if the user scrolls back up. I have this working perfectly on my localhost, but when I upload it online, the sticky nav just keeps jumping straight to the top as soon as you even scroll a little bit of the page, and it never returns to its normal position.

The jQuery concerned is:

```
var yOffset = $("#local-nav-wrapper").offset().top;
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > yOffset) {
        $("#local-nav-wrapper").css({
            'top': 0,
            'bottom': 'auto',
            'position': 'fixed'
        });
    } else {
        $("#local-nav-wrapper").css({
            'top': 'auto',
            'bottom': 0,
            'position': 'absolute'
        });
    }
});
```

The CSS concerned is:

```
#local-nav-wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    padding: 10px 0;
    z-index: 6000;
}
```

Comment: the nav works fine on my screen, MAC FF 11

Comment: yea it's just webkit browsers that seem to pose the issue.

Comment: just tried on mac chrome and it works as well

Answer (score 1):

If you work in IE  try and replace `$(window).scrollTop()` with `document.documentElement.scrollTop` or `window.scroll(0,0)`. Maybe it helps.

Comment: It didn't work at all when I tried this, anymore suggestions? Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am troubleshooting the same problem. I found [this thread on css tricks](https://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/sticky-nav-jumping-sometimes-in-webkit-browsers/) that suggests that:

> When it loads in localhost it’s really fast anad it gets the correct value, but on the server it gets the value before the elements are set.